# Strange issue with MUI/Material UI multiselect component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

this is my code : [codesandbox multiselect demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselect-material-demo-forked-3ezg3?file=/MultiSelectDemo.js)

I need to extract unique items from an array based on id and display resulting array as options. I'm using MUI Select component.

It works when I use this to create the new array with distinct id value:

`dictinctItems.push(item);`

But this doesn't work for some reason.

`dictinctItems.push({ id: item.id, label: item.label });`

Whats wrong with the second form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you do `dictinctItems.push(item);` you are pushing the reference of the same object into the list and when you do `dictinctItems.push({ id: item.id, label: item.label });` you are pushing a new object every time.

In your component each time a new value is being selected you change the state in the `handleChange` which will trigger a re-render, this re-render will again run your `getDistinctItemsById` function at the top of the component and return a new list when you do `dictinctItems.push({ id: item.id, label: item.label });`.

This can be fixed if you use `useMemo` that is change

```
const dictinctItems = getDistinctItemsById(listData)
```

to

```
const dictinctItems = useMemo(() =>getDistinctItemsById(listData), [])
```

and you will always have the same objects on every re-render, no matter whether you use `dictinctItems.push(item);` or `dictinctItems.push({ id: item.id, label: item.label });`

### Just to make to understand a bit more about copying reference and value in javascript

Just look at this example below

```
let stringValue = 'Hi';
const objValue = {id: "1", label: 'P1'};

// for primitive value, it copy gets pushed to array
const myArray = [];
myArray.push(stringValue);        // push copy of 'Hi' here
stringValue = 'Hi how are you';   // change 'Hi' to 'Hi how are you'
console.log(myArray[0]);          // myArray still contains 'Hi'

// for objects, its reference gets pushed
const newArray = [];
newArray.push(objValue);         // puts object reference into the array
objValue.id = "2";               // change 'id' property
console.log(newArray[0].id);     // here id will be changed to '2'
```